# Get css animation property with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've defined an animations with CSS which will start by adding a class with jQuery to a defined element like in the following Example:

jQuery (I'm testing in Firefox):

```
$(document).on('click', 'h1 > span:first-child', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('animate');
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').length);   // 1 (Element exists)
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').css('animation')); // Empty string
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').css('-moz-animation')); // Empty string
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').css('-webkit-animation')); // undefined of course ;) 
});
```

CSS animation (working fine)

```
// The animation testen was defined before an is working an assign class to span element
body h1 span.animate {
  -webkit-animation: testen 5s 1;
  -moz-animation: testen 5s 1;
  -ms-animation: testen 5s 1;
  -o-animation: testen 5s 1;
  animation: testen 5s 1;
}
```

What's might be the reason that I always get an empty String instead of something like this?

```
animation: testen 5s 1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the separate values instead of the bundle? (duration, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the values directly instead of the bundle:

```
$(document).on('click', 'h1 > span:first-child', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('animate');
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').length);   // 1 (Element exists)
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').css('animation-duration')); // 5s
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').css('-moz-animation-duration')); // 5s
    console.log($('h1 > span.animate').css('-webkit-animation-duration')); // 5s
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DXqmE/1/)</kbd>