# jquery button trigger css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make a button which have jquery function can trigger the css which will flip the card.
i do not know Trigger , toggle or addClass to use. Help thanks !
I actually want it to automatically flip from num 1 to 10.
With looping , how is it going to achieve ?

html

```
<div class="panel" id="card2">
    <div class="front card">
        <img src="0.png">
    </div>
    <div class="back card">
        <img src="2.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .2s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);  
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);  

}

.panel:hover .front, .togglefront {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.panel:hover .back ,.toggleback{
    z-index: 2;   
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear enough

Comment: @jibinMathew I want to make a button, which when i click it , it will flip the card

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360194/triggering-a-css-animation-with-jquery

Try this probably this might help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get css animation property with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229955/get-css-animation-property-with-jquery)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360194/triggering-a-css-animation-with-jquery

This might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQUERY**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
       $('.front').addClass('front-flip');
       $('.back').addClass('back-flip');
    });
```

You'll need to create a `<button>` element, and assign an event handler to that button using the code above. Essentially you'll create two new classes `front-flip` and `back-flip` which mimic the same CSS that you're currently assigning on hover to flip the card/image over.

See working example here - should set you on the right path [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gkd2f0xq/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery UI's [`.switchClass()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) function to remove and add the specified class. Here is an example:

```js
$("#flip").click(function() {
  $(".card").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("front")) {
      $(this).switchClass("front", "back");
      return;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass("back")) {
      $(this).switchClass("back", "front");
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  -ms-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
}
.back {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.panel:hover .front,
.togglefront {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.panel:hover .back,
.toggleback {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="flip">Flip!</button>
<div class="front card">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSjRc.jpg">
</div>
<div class="back card">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5qcg.jpg">
</div>
```

Or you just use the [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) functions. Here is an example without jQuery UI:

```
$("#flip").click(function () {
    $(".card").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("front")) {
            $(this).removeClass("front");
            $(this).addClass("back");
            return;
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass("back")) {
            $(this).removeClass("back");
            $(this).addClass("front");
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/994xmc3s/4/)**

I'm not sure this is the right way to do that, but it's work and you can improve it :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="panel panel_1" id="card2">
    <div class="front card">
        <img src="http://fr.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211813364.png">
    </div>
    <div class="back card">
        <img src="http://fr.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211808744.png">
    </div>
</div>

<button id='flip_card'>Flip card</button>
```

**CSS :**

```
.panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .2s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);  
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);  

}
```

**JS :**

```
//Flip card function
$('#flip_card').click(function(){
    var card_id = 'card2';

    if($('#'+card_id+' .front').css('z-index')==1)
        flip_front(card_id);
    else
        flip_back(card_id);
});

//Flip back of card 
flip_back = function(card_id){

    $('#'+card_id+' .front').css({
      "z-index": 1, "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(180deg)", "-ms-transform": "rotateY(180deg)", "-moz-transform": "rotateY(180deg)", "transform": "rotateY(180deg)"
    });

    $('#'+card_id+' .back').css({
       "z-index": 2, "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(0deg)", "-ms-transform": "rotateY(0deg)", "-moz-transform": "rotateY(0deg)", "transform": "rotateY(0deg)"
    });
}

//Flip front of card 
flip_front = function(card_id){

    $('#'+card_id+' .back').css({
      "z-index": 1, "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(180deg)", "-ms-transform": "rotateY(180deg)", "-moz-transform": "rotateY(180deg)", "transform": "rotateY(180deg)"
    });

    $('#'+card_id+' .front').css({
       "z-index": 2, "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(0deg)", "-ms-transform": "rotateY(0deg)", "-moz-transform": "rotateY(0deg)", "transform": "rotateY(0deg)"
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.